# Scheme language add one to every list element

Tags: scheme

Here is the problem:
Define a function addOne, which takes a list of numbers and returns a list where each number in the input list is increased by one. For example, (addOne ′(1 2 3 4)) should return (2 3 4 5), and (addOne ′(2 4 6 8)) should return (3 5 7 9).

I'm new for scheme language, need the help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using map:

```
(define (add-one nums)
   (map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to think of a simple solution to this problem. I created a helper procedure, `plus1`, which takes in a number and returns the sum of that number and 1:

```
 (define (plus1 x)
   (+ x 1))
```

Then, I defined `addOne` using `map`:

```
(define (addOne lst)
  (map plus1 lst))
```

Basically, `map` takes in two arguments: a procedure and a list. It applies that procedure to every item of that list, then returns the modified list according to that procedure. In this case, the `map` part of `addOne` just takes every item of the inputted list, adds 1 to it, and returns the new list.

Please respond with questions or feedback!